# How to adjust the x-axis width to fit and display each string of the words in the plot?

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, width

I am trying to set the width to be automatically adjusted to fit each string of words in the x-axis. The words are "Fleet", "Services", "Information Technology" ... etc (about 10 in total)

```
x = df.Category.astype(str)
y = df.Amount
plt.scatter(x,np.e**y,label ="$ Amount", color = "k", marker = "*", s = 3)
```

[image]

See the red box on x-axis. Need those words spread out clearly.

Comment: Do they have to be horizontal? You could always rotate them for a fairly easy solution

Comment: Adjusting the figure size such that the range of one data unit expands by the space of the largest ticklabel text would be possible; but this is surely not an easy solution if it's desired to be accurate. So I would wait to spend effort into providing such answer unit it is confirmed that rotating the ticks is not an option here (because that's much simpler and respective solutions already exist in other answers).

Comment: If you don't want to have diagonal or vertical text, you could also swap x- and y-data, so that the categories are printed up the y-axis. Then they don't overlap and are readable without turning your head...

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be (as commented above) to simply swap x and y to have readable category names on the y-axis:

[image]

---

```
# Code to reproduce image above:

# import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# np.random.seed(42)
# cats = ['Facility', 'Fleet', 'Services', 'Information Technology', 'Facility2', 'Fleet2', 'Services2', 'Information Technology2']
# df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': np.random.choice(cats, 100000), 'Amount': np.random.random(100000)*750})
# x = df.Category.astype(str)
# y = df.Amount
plt.scatter(np.e**y, x, label ="$ Amount", color = "k", marker = "*", s = 3)
# plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: thank you all with your suggestions. great help on the axis change recommendation :).